# Horizontal scroll bars in tables

Tags: css

In the following  code,

```
<table id=\"preview_table\" class=\"preview_table\" cellspacing=\"0\" border=\"1\" width=\"%s\"><tr  bgcolor=\"lightgrey\" width=\"%s\"><th>Category</th>
<th>Grade</th>
<th>Grade</th>
<th>Grade</th>
<th>Grade</th><th>Grade</th>
<th>Grade</th>
<th>Grade</th>
<th>Grade</th>
<th>Grade</th>
 <th>Grade</th>
 <th>Grade</th>
 </tr><tr><th></th>
<th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th></tr>
 </table>
```

In the above table how to fix the table width such that the horizontal scroll bar doesnt appear in the browser and the cells are equally aligned for what ever the size it has the contents

Thanks..

Comment: What do you want to happen instead? If it's too wide, it has to do something.

Comment: What are the values of the 3 string variables you have?

Comment: table width and row width is 100%, preview table%s was a typo..

Comment: @Hulk, was may answer sufficient? If so, could you accept it? If not, what didn't work about it? See [How do I ask questions here?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) in the FAQ.

Answer (score 0):

Set the *table-layout* to *fixed* and then set the *width* of the table as well (table-layout will only work when the width is explicitly set). The following CSS should do the trick:

```
<style type="text/css">
.preview_table {
 table-layout:fixed;
 width:100%; // You may need to change this depending on padding/margins/etc
}
</style>
```